# Unity Android build fails, error : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x

Tags: unity

Can't build for Android, error log:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed,
```

And this is in it's description:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Gradle libraries were missing,

Instead of directly building apk, tried to "Export Project", then opened it in Android Studio.

It will start to download the requirements. After the required Gradle libraries are installed, try to build it in Android studio. Directly building apk files in Unity will work afterwards.

Comment: What if you're working offline, how can you manually install those dependencies?

Comment: @bluejayke try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291708/1235063

Comment: Interesting is there a way to do that without even Android studio? I downloaded the complete zip but how do I manually install it?

Comment: Use the same location in the answer above, but instead of opening Android Studio, open Unity. Check if it works.

Comment: What do you mean, where is there an option to select the full Gradle in unity

Comment: If you have the error above, it's already using gradle! you don't need to change anything. just try to build in Unity.

Comment: The thing is it's not, because I have an offline machine, and what unity usually does on the first build is GET gradle from the server, but how can I setup Gradle without internet on the machine at all??